# 2 Page Product Configuration

Tags: magento-1.9, product, php, javascript

How would I configure Magento 1.9 product pages to be configured in a 2 page method. I am doing development for a Jewelry Retailer and in this industry, generally you would select the Ring Setting first and then add that to cart and then the next page would be to pick the diamond that fits the ring. So, it would need to flow from the ring setting page directly to the diamond selector page and once that is selected, then the customer will be directed to the shopping cart. Let me know and thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try totally overhauling the default checkout process

1. Create custom template file for the 'checkout' button. I think it would be within the catalog_product_view layout
2. Your custom button need to call whatever controller action that will handle the process of loading the diamonds page. This can be within your own custom module (ie app > code > local > yourmodule)
3. Create a totally new page to handle the diamond selection page.
4. Add the "Checkout" button to this new diamond page and have it added to checkout (you must also make sure you are saving your diamond selection to the product).

*You can do this by making sure this is added to your sales_quote manually. The order, could theoretically, show two simple products to make up this product. (1) the ring setting/size and (2) the diamond.

Comment: There is a diamond feed that the diamonds are selected from. I do not want to add that to the product page and instead, want to have a 2 page configuration for choosing the ring setting and then the next page has the diamond feed and the customer can choose the diamond they would like to put in the ring next. You can view a similar setup on brilliantearth.com and bluenile.com. Start with a Setting then pick the diamond, then products are added to cart.